# Using Sharepoint to Produce a Word/PDF Document from HTML

Tags: sharepoint, pdf, publish

I have a large document that has been written in HTML that I want to update and produce a PDF/Word document from. Is there a way to use Sharepoint to cut and paste the individual HTML pages into a hierarchical structure and then publish the whole as a single PDF or Word document?

Bonus points for being able to deal with linked attachments.

Comment: No free solutions. Also what does sharepoint has to do with the HTML pages? Are they stored in a sharepoint library?

Comment: @Shoban, SharePoint consists of HTML Pages. I suspect that Peter's document is an HTML based WIKI.

Comment: In the end we wrote a VB macro to concatenate all of the HTML files into a Word document.